# Hide/Show Element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to learn jQuery and Javascript. I want to hide and show a Div Element (div2) with a button on a webpage using a button I have placed on the page. However, I want the jQuery code to be placed in a separate file referenced later on (like a custom .css file). Here's my basic code:

```css
#div1{
 background-color: aquamarine; 
}

#div2{
 background-color: firebrick; 
}

#hide_show{
 
background-color: cornflowerblue;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
 
 <head>
  
   
    <link href="special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
  </head>

 <body>  

  <div id ="div1">
   
   this is a container
   
  </div>
  
  <div id = "div2">
  
   This is another div.
  
  </div>
  
  <button type="button" id ="hide_show">Click Me!</button>
 

 </body>
 
</html>
```

Referencing the file isn't an issue. However, how do I go ahead with writing the Javascript file? Also, does the text editor of your choice affect how Javascript is executed on the website? I'm currently using codeblocks.

Thanks.

Comment: `head` tag should be out of `body` tag

Comment: html syntax is invalid . You need to fix that first . use website http://fixmyhtml.com/ . Then you can use id as selector to hide and show . $('#div2').hide()

Comment: Oh didn't see that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No, CodeBlocks won't affect your file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#hide_show').click(()=>{ // subscribe to button click event
     $('#div2').fadeToggle(); // animate show hide toggle
     // $('#div2').toggle(); // without animation effect
});
```

Methods [**.fadeToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) or [**.toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) might help.

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes things a lot easier!

Answer (score 2):

Hi so your html file should first reference Jquery then in your JS file you can do:

```
$('#hide_show').on('click', function(event){
  $('#div2').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! The added transitional effect is quite neat!

Comment: @Hamza You should probably give credit to him by pressing the checkmark below the score of the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

html syntax is invalid . You need to fix that first . use website http://fixmyhtml.com
then use you can write jquery

```
$('#hide_show').click(function(){
  $('#div2').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For questions like these, I would recommend you the website https://w3schools.com.

It will tell you how to properly include the JQuery library and and is a good reference site for programming syntax.

For example, on https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp ,it says:

> If you don't want to download and host jQuery yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network).
>
> Both Google and Microsoft host jQuery.
>
> To use jQuery from Google or Microsoft, use one of the following:

**Google:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Microsoft:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also, https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp tells you how to use the `toggle` method which actually has a lot of tidbits some people would not normally know

Answer (score 1):

A good method to use in this case would be `.toggle()`. It basically applies `.show()` if element is hidden and `.hide()` if its shown.

Example:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', e => {
  $($(e.target).data('target')).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-target="#div1">Toggle #div1</button>
<button type="button" data-target="#div2">Toggle #div2</button>

<div id="div1">
  this is a container.
</div>
<div id="div2">
  This is another div.
</div>
```

You'll also notice I'm getting the targeted element for the action from the clicked element, dynamically (the click event gets passed to the function and its `target` property references the target of the event. `$(e.target).data('target')` basically reads the `data-target` attribute of the clicked element), so the above code will make any number of buttons work, without any modifications.

```
<button type="button" data-target="#div3">Toggle #div3</button>
```

... will toggle any element with `id="div3"`.

Going further, you might not want this behavior bound on **all** your buttons that happen to have a `data-target` attribute. So let's limit it to only buttons that have a `toggler` class and that also have a `data-target` attribute:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.toggler[data-target]', e => {
  $($(e.target).data('target')).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggler" type="button" data-target="#div1">Toggle #div1</button>
<button type="button" data-target="#div2">Toggle #div2</button>

<div id="div1">
  this is a container.
</div>
<div id="div2">
  This is another div.
</div>
```

As you can see, now only the first button works, because the second one doesn't meet the conditions for the selector: `button.toggler[data-target]` (it doesn't have the `toggler` class - but if you do add it, it will start working).

---

Besides `.toggle()`, `.show()` and `.hide()` methods which simply change the `display` property of the element, jQuery comes with two helper classes for toggling display: [fading](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) and [sliding](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/), each with its own specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Hide show element on button click**
In this example  I use one single function for hide show element on click so I can use this function multiple time. by passing parameter on any button click function

```js
let CustomeToggle = (divId,readMoreText)=>{
            divId.toggle();
            switch($(readMoreText).text()){
                case 'Read more':
                $(readMoreText).text('Less')
                break;
                case 'Less':
                $(readMoreText).text('Read more')
                break;
                case 'view more':
                $(readMoreText).text('less view')
                break;
                case 'less view':
                $(readMoreText).text('view more')
                break;
                default:
                $(readMoreText).text('Read More')   
            }
        }

        $('#alphaReadmore').click(function(){
            CustomeToggle($('.FirstDiv'),this)
        })

        $('#count_viewmore').click(function(){
            CustomeToggle($('.secondDiv'),this)
        })
```

```css
a{
 color:blue;
 display:block;
 margin-top:15px;
 cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<p>A B C D<span class="FirstDiv" style="display: none;"> E F G H</span>
<br>
<a id="alphaReadmore">Read more</a> 
</p>

<br><br>

<p>1 2 3 4 5<span class="secondDiv" style="display: none;"> 6 7 8 9 10</span>
<br>
<a id="count_viewmore">view more</a> 
</p>
```